# Does assigning the result of a subroutine result in a copy of the data?

Tags: perl, reference, pass-by-value

I'm trying to understand if assigning the result of a subroutine results in the copying of that data.

```
sub maketext { 'text' };

my $foo = maketext();
my $foo_ref = \$foo;

my $bar_ref = \maketext();
```

In the above example, will the creation of `$foo_ref` result in one more copy than the creation of `$bar_ref`?

How can I convince myself of their equivalence or unequivalence?

Comment: Even thinking about the amount of time spent here is a huge mistake. You should think which code is more readable. And in the case your result is so huge, that copying does have a real impact, you should be returning a reference.

Comment: "Premature optimisation is the root of all evil". Don't even think about this, it's trivial. Except when it's not, but for that you use a code profiler.

Comment: It's not necessarily micro-optimization. I don't know the answer, and I'm curious to learn what it is, just because.

Comment: Context: I was working with a function that called `WWW::Mechanize::content` and passed the result to another function. I was wondering if I wrote `my $content_ref = \$mech->content; foo($content_ref)` or `my $content = $mech->content; foo(\$content);` made a difference, purely out of interest. Now I understand the later will copy the scalar, but not the underlying data, so the difference is negligible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data copy appears to happen

```
sub maketext {
    my $text = 'text';
    say \$text;
    return $text;
}

my $bar_ref = \maketext();
say $bar_ref;
```

This prints

```
SCALAR(0x11f5818)
SCALAR(0x11cfa68)
```

The addresses of data created in the sub and of what `$bar_ref` points to are not the same.

On the face of it, as the function returns the data has to be copied, and the reference to that is taken.

The other possibility would be that the reference to the original data is kept even as it goes out of scope, like it happens in closures.  However, here the function returns *first* and its return is then manipulated. So I don't see how any mechanism would know what is done with data, so the data is duly copied.

You are creating an anonymous scalar reference, but out of the function return.

---

A way to create a reference to a scalar without having the corresponding variable around is

```
my $scalar_ref = \do { my $var };
```

or with `do { \my $var }`, or in your case with a sub

```
sub anon_scalar_ref {
    # ...
    return \my $var;
}
```

However, I don't see what use you'd have of this.  Perhaps you want to do

```
sub maketext {
    # ... define $text ...
    return \$text;
}
```

When you assign the return of this to a variable no extra data copies are made, since it is the reference that is returned.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it copies.

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );

sub maketext {
    my $text = 'text';
    Dump($text);
    return $text;
}

my $ref = \maketext();
Dump($$ref);
```

Output:

```
SV = PV(0x8b18a0) at 0x8dbe38   <-- $text is at 0x8dbe38
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x8d9f70 "text"\0        <-- String buffer at 0x8d9f70
  CUR = 4
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
SV = PV(0x8b1920) at 0x8b0cc8   <-- $$ref is at 0x8b0cc8
  REFCNT = 1
  FLAGS = (POK,IsCOW,pPOK)
  PV = 0x8d9f70 "text"\0        <-- String buffer at 0x8d9f70
  CUR = 4
  LEN = 10
  COW_REFCNT = 1
```

However, the string buffer isn't copied thanks to the copy-on-write (COW) feature. In fact, it wasn't even copied when you did `my $text = 'text';` for the very same reason. That means that the constant, `$text` and `$$ref` are all sharing the same string buffer (until an one of their string buffers is edited) even though they are entirely different scalars.

You can get away from from having the returned value copied by using an lvalue sub.

```
use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );

sub maketext :lvalue {
    my $text = 'text';
    Dump($text);
    return $text;
}

my $ref = \maketext();
Dump($$ref);
```

Output:

```
SV = PV(0xe43c80) at 0xe6e238
[...]
SV = PV(0xe43c80) at 0xe6e238
[...]
```

Comment: Your first sentence is "Yes, it copies", but after reading the COW part of your answer, it seems like the definition of "data" in my question needs to be more specific. From this answer I understand the *scalar* is copied, but not the underlying string buffer (until the value is modified).

I notice from the lvalue sub, that although it avoids the copy, it will create a new scalar every call (still with the same PV), whereas the non-lvalue version reuses the same variable.

Comment: `my` variables are indeed reused when possible (determined at the time the sub exits). If a `my` variable is returned from an lvalue sub, it's obviously not possible to reuse it.

Comment: Note that COW is relatively new, but there was another optimization in place before that: buffer stealing from temps. That means it that is a "temporary" is returned from a sub, it's buffer will be "stolen" rather than copied. A temporary is a constructed value (e.g. one obtained from concatenation, substr, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Perl *has to copy* the data. Otherwise any subsequent modification to the variable `$foo` would be an attempt to modify the string constant `'text'`, which would cause your code to die.

That is what happens in

```
for ( 'text' ) {
    $_ = 'test';
}
```

which raises the error

> Modification of a read-only value attempted